# Sort MongoDB documents by their distance to a given point

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb

I have a MongoDB collection. Each document in the collection has x,y coordinations representing a position on a grid. Given a point (x',y') I would like to retrieve the top k documents which their position is closest to (x',y') by Euclidean distance. I'm using MongoDB from a rails app. I would like to do the calculation on the DB if it's possible. How can I do it?

Comment: A geonear query should do this by default

Answer (score 1):

If you store the coordinates as an array [x, y], you just need to create a geospatial index ("2d") on that field.

To query the index:

```
db.runCommand({geoNear: <collection>, near: [x, y], limit: k})
```

If you are on MongoDB 2.4, the preferred way is to use the GeoJSON format (i.e. {type: "Point", coordinates: [x, y]}) and a "2dsphere" index, but the legacy format is also supported.

To query the index:

```
db.runCommand({geoNear: <collection>, near: {type: "Point", coordinates:[x, y]}, limit: k})
```

The geoNear command returns the results ordered by distance.

Here is the documentation:

- 2d index - http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/2d/
- 2dsphere index (2.4) - http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/2dsphere/